# Row Level Security Tabular model some Bridge tables/Dimensions

Tags: security, ssas-tabular

I'm working with a tabular model and I have to create a specific Role.

The problem I have is that the security is not propagating to the fact table.

I have 1 Fact Table, 1 Security table, 3 Dimensions with a Bridge table to avoid many to many.
[image: model]

The relationship that I have from bridge to dimension is to both tables.  In addition in the roles I have DAX code in each dimension to find the user.

The problem I have is that when I test the roles, The user can see only the values of the dimensions that is allowed for this user, this part is working well but the total is the total of the fact table.

Example:

| Entity | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 |
| **Total** | **3000 (Fact table total)** |

I have tried to mark the option "Row Level Security". When I applied it in 1 of them works for this dimension. But If I do the same for all dimensions doesn't work.

I hope the message is understandable and we can find a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what your tables and relationships are.  Please clarify.  This is one case where a picture is useful.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. I have created a template of a part of my model.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvCZf.jpg